# CSS3 Transform Translate3D IE10

Tags: css, transform, internet-explorer-10, translate3d

according to IE 10's supported technologies what I am trying to accomplish should be working, but I cannot figure out what is going on. in firefox and chrome it works just like it should, but in IE10 it is rendered incorrectly.

I have exhausted IE's support doc's, and like I said, this should be working.

here is the JS Fiddle [JSFiddle]: http://jsfiddle.net/qzDV3/1/

```
body
{
    background-color:Blue;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#tumble
{
    position:absolute;
    top:70%;
    left:5%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
#tumble.tumble
{
    left:100%;
    top:85%;
    -webkit-transform:rotate3d(1, -1, 1, 256deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate3d(1, -1, 1, 256deg);
    transform:rotate3d(1, -1, 1, 256deg);
}
.box
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform:rotate3d(1, 1, 1, -30deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate3d(1, 1, 1, -30deg);
    transform:rotate3d(1, 1, 1, -30deg);
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
.box.rotate
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate3d(1, -1, 1, 256deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate3d(1, -1, 1, 256deg);
    transform:rotate3d(1, -1, 1, 256deg);
}
.front, .back
{
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.front
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,100px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,100px);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,100px);
}
.back
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,-100px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,-100px);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,-100px);
}
.left, .right
{
    top:0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
.left
{
    left:-100px;
}
.right
{
    left:100px;
}
.front, .back, .left, .right, .bottom
{
    position:absolute;
    border:2px solid #CF985D;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    background-image:url(SRC/Images/cardboard_texture_02.jpg);
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.bottom
{
    top:100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
.top1, .top2
{
    position:absolute;
    border:2px solid #CF985D;
    background-image:url(SRC/Images/cardboard_texture_02.jpg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.top1, .top2
{
    top:0px;
    left:0;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
}
.top2
{
    right:0;
}
.outer1, .outer2
{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.outer1
{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
.outer2
{
    -webkit-transition: all 2s bounce;
    -moz-transition: all 2s bounce;
    transition: all 2s bounce;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(180deg);
}
.outer1:hover
{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(180deg);
}
.outer2:hover
{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg);
}
.outer1
{
    left:-100px;
    top:-100px;
}
.outer2
{
    right:-300px;
    top:-100px;
}
.outer1.close
{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(180deg);
}
.outer2.close
{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: From Microsoft's own [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#the_ms_transform_style_property): Internet Explorer 10 does not support the `preserve-3d` keyword. You can work around this by manually applying the parent element's transform to each of the child elements in addition to the child element's normal transform.

Answer (score 3):

IE10 does not support preserve-3d option for transform-style.

[CSS3 - 3D Flip Animation - IE10 transform-origin: preserve-3d workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474210/css3-3d-flip-animation-ie10-transform-origin-preserve-3d-workaround)

[Why doesn't IE10 display nested CSS3 3D transformed elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609646/why-doesnt-ie10-display-nested-css3-3d-transformed-elements)