# How to recreate perspective-origin effect by transforming child elements?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, css-transforms

So after struggeling with IE [glitches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622441/why-is-backface-visibility-hidden-not-working-in-ie10-when-perspective-is-applie) and [incompatibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609646/why-doesnt-ie10-display-nested-css3-3d-transformed-elements), I've finally got my correctly sized cuboid working (**update:** [here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/LpRuy/) of it). Animating requires to animate all sides separately instead of a single parent element, however this seems to be the only way to get it working in IE.

Using a single cuboid works fine, multiple cuboids however are problematic, since perspective is applied to the single transformed elements (which is necessary in order to work in IE) they do all look the same, regardless of their position on the stage:

http://jsfiddle.net/YsPmm/

If perspective would be applied to the stage, the vanishing point would sit in its center, causing the child objects to be transformed accordingly, and that's what I'm trying to recreate (while maintaining IE compatibility!):

http://jsfiddle.net/kbhej/

Unfortunately it looks like applying perspective-origin to the single elements doesn't work, so I'm wondering if anyone has any other ideas how to achieve this effect?

---

### Code for the jsfiddle examples

Perspective on single elements:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .stage {
            width: 800px;
            height: 800px;
            background: #f6f6f6;
        }
        .wrapper, .top, .front{
            position: absolute;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;

            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
        }
        .wrapper:nth-child(1) {
            z-index: 4;
        }
        .wrapper:nth-child(2) {
            left: 200px;
            z-index: 3;
        }
        .wrapper:nth-child(3) {
            left: 400px;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        .wrapper:nth-child(4) {
            left: 600px;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .top {
            background-color: #00ff00;

            -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -100px;
               -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% -100px;
                    transform-origin: 50% 50% -100px;

            -webkit-transform: perspective(200px) translateZ(-100px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-45deg);
               -moz-transform: perspective(200px) translateZ(-100px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-45deg);
                    transform: perspective(200px) translateZ(-100px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-45deg);
        }

        .front {
            background-color: #ff0000;

            -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -100px;
               -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% -100px;
                    transform-origin: 50% 50% -100px;

            -webkit-transform: perspective(200px) translateZ(-100px) rotateX(-45deg);
               -moz-transform: perspective(200px) translateZ(-100px) rotateX(-45deg);
                    transform: perspective(200px) translateZ(-100px) rotateX(-45deg);
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='stage'>
            <div class='wrapper'>
                <div class='top'></div>
                <div class='front'></div>
            </div>

            <div class='wrapper'>
                <div class='top'></div>
                <div class='front'></div>
            </div>

            <div class='wrapper'>
                <div class='top'></div>
                <div class='front'></div>
            </div>

            <div class='wrapper'>
                <div class='top'></div>
                <div class='front'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Perspective on the stage:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .stage {
            width: 800px;
            height: 800px;
            background: #f6f6f6;

            -webkit-perspective: 800px;
               -moz-perspective: 800px;
                    perspective: 800px;
        }
        .wrapper, .top, .front{
            position: absolute;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;

            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;

            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
               -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                    transform-style: preserve-3d;
        }
        .wrapper:nth-child(1) {
            z-index: 4;
        }
        .wrapper:nth-child(2) {
            left: 200px;
            z-index: 3;
        }
        .wrapper:nth-child(3) {
            left: 400px;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        .wrapper:nth-child(4) {
            left: 600px;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .wrapper {    
            -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -45deg) translate3d(0, 50px, 50px);
               -moz-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -45deg) translate3d(0, 50px, 50px);
                    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -45deg) translate3d(0, 50px, 50px);
        }

        .top {
            background-color: #00ff00;
            -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg) translate3d(0, -100px, 100px);
               -moz-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg) translate3d(0, -100px, 100px);
                    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg) translate3d(0, -100px, 100px);
        }

        .front {
            background-color: #ff0000;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='stage'>
            <div class='wrapper'>
                <div class='top'></div>
                <div class='front'></div>
            </div>

            <div class='wrapper'>
                <div class='top'></div>
                <div class='front'></div>
            </div>

            <div class='wrapper'>
                <div class='top'></div>
                <div class='front'></div>
            </div>

            <div class='wrapper'>
                <div class='top'></div>
                <div class='front'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here we go, as [shown by vals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17369221/1392379), perspective is respected when using `transform:translate` to position the faces on the stage, so I figured that the trick is to position the cuboid wrappes in the center of the stage, apply perspective using the `perspective()` function, and then translate the faces positions accordingly.

Here's an example, it works fine (fine as in *as expected*) in IE10/11 and Chrome, in Firefox there's a lot of flickering when the faces of the individual cubes intersect each other, and in Safari (for Windows) the faces are clipped when they intersect (tough it looks like this is actually the correct behaviour, and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=689498), [Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116710) and IE are wrong. **update** Let me take that back, actually it looks like Safari is doing it wrong since only elements in the same [3d rendering context](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#d-rendering-context) are [ment to intersect](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-3d-rendering)). However, the main goal was IE compatibiilty, and even though it's a an annoyingly large amount of extra CSS, it's working, so...

http://jsfiddle.net/EDzXM/

---

#### Code for the jsfiddle example

HTML:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='front'>Front</div>
    <div class='back'>Back</div>
    <div class='top'>Top</div>
    <div class='bottom'>Bottom</div>
    <div class='left'>Left</div>
    <div class='right'>Right</div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='front'>Front</div>
    <div class='back'>Back</div>
    <div class='top'>Top</div>
    <div class='bottom'>Bottom</div>
    <div class='left'>Left</div>
    <div class='right'>Right</div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='front'>Front</div>
    <div class='back'>Back</div>
    <div class='top'>Top</div>
    <div class='bottom'>Bottom</div>
    <div class='left'>Left</div>
    <div class='right'>Right</div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='front'>Front</div>
    <div class='back'>Back</div>
    <div class='top'>Top</div>
    <div class='bottom'>Bottom</div>
    <div class='left'>Left</div>
    <div class='right'>Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -120px;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(1) {
    z-index: 1;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(2) {
    z-index: 2;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(3) {
    z-index: 1;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(4) {
    z-index: 0;
}
.top, .front, .back, .bottom, .left, .right {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 400px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 400px;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-animation-duration: 25s;
    animation-duration: 25s;

    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.top, .bottom {
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
}
.left, .right {
    width: 300px;
}
.front, .back {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -150px;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% -150px;
}
.top, .bottom {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -200px;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% -200px;
}
.left, .right {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -120px;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% -120px;
}
.front {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.back {
    background-color: #00cc00;
}
.top {
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
.bottom {
    background-color: #cccc00;
}
.left {
    background-color: #00cccc;
}
.right {
    background-color: #ff00ff;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(1) .front {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-front-0;
    animation-name: rotate-front-0;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(1) .back {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-back-0;
    animation-name: rotate-back-0;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(1) .top {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-top-0;
    animation-name: rotate-top-0;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(1) .bottom {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-bottom-0;
    animation-name: rotate-bottom-0;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(1) .left {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-left-0;
    animation-name: rotate-left-0;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(1) .right {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-right-0;
    animation-name: rotate-right-0;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(2) .front {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-front-1;
    animation-name: rotate-front-1;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(2) .back {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-back-1;
    animation-name: rotate-back-1;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(2) .top {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-top-1;
    animation-name: rotate-top-1;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(2) .bottom {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-bottom-1;
    animation-name: rotate-bottom-1;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(2) .left {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-left-1;
    animation-name: rotate-left-1;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(2) .right {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-right-1;
    animation-name: rotate-right-1;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(3) .front {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-front-2;
    animation-name: rotate-front-2;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(3) .back {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-back-2;
    animation-name: rotate-back-2;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(3) .top {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-top-2;
    animation-name: rotate-top-2;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(3) .bottom {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-bottom-2;
    animation-name: rotate-bottom-2;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(3) .left {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-left-2;
    animation-name: rotate-left-2;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(3) .right {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-right-2;
    animation-name: rotate-right-2;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(4) .front {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-front-3;
    animation-name: rotate-front-3;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(4) .back {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-back-3;
    animation-name: rotate-back-3;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(4) .top {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-top-3;
    animation-name: rotate-top-3;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(4) .bottom {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-bottom-3;
    animation-name: rotate-bottom-3;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(4) .left {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-left-3;
    animation-name: rotate-left-3;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(4) .right {

    -webkit-animation-name: rotate-right-3;
    animation-name: rotate-right-3;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-front-0 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-back-0 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-top-0 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateZ(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-bottom-0 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateZ(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-left-0 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-right-0 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(-360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-front-1 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-back-1 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-top-1 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateZ(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-bottom-1 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateZ(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-left-1 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-right-1 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(-360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-front-2 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-back-2 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-top-2 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateZ(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-bottom-2 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateZ(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-left-2 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-right-2 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(-360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-front-3 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-back-3 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-top-3 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateZ(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-bottom-3 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateZ(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-left-3 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-right-3 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(-360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}


@keyframes rotate-front-0 {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-back-0 {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-top-0 {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateZ(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-bottom-0 {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateZ(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-left-0 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-right-0 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(-360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-front-1 {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-back-1 {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-top-1 {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateZ(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-bottom-1 {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateZ(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-left-1 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-right-1 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(-120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(-360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-front-2 {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-back-2 {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-top-2 {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateZ(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-bottom-2 {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateZ(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-left-2 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-right-2 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(120px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(-360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-front-3 {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-back-3 {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-top-3 {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateZ(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-bottom-3 {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateX(-0deg) rotateZ(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(50px) perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateX(-360deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-left-3 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate-right-3 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-30px) perspective(1920px) translateX(360px) translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(-360deg) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a beautiful effect! I hate to think how much time that took to develop. With a similar (but much less complex) problem, I ended up just using a different class for IE users and showing them a flat object as punishment for their folly.

Answer (score 3):

## [I.E. demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/GkyJd/)

I have keept your original HTML, and changed the CSS to this one:

```
.stage {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    background: #f6f6f6;

    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
        
}
.wrapper, .top, .front{
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;

-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(1) {
z-index: 4;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(2) {
left: 0px;
z-index: 3; 
}
.wrapper:nth-child(3) {
left: 0px;
z-index: 2;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(4) {
left: 0px;
z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper {    
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -45deg) translate3d(0, 50px, 50px);
   -moz-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -45deg) translate3d(0, 50px, 50px);
}

.top {
background-color: #00ff00;
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg) translate3d(0, -100px, 100px);
   -moz-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg) translate3d(0, -100px, 100px);
}

.front {
background-color: #ff0000;
}

/* IE specific */
.wrapper {
perspective: 800px;
perspective-origin: 400px;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(1) .top {
transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -45deg) translate3d(0, 50px, 50px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg)      translate3d(0, -100px, 100px);
}
.wrapper:nth-child(1) .front {
transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -45deg) translate3d(0, 50px, 50px);
}
.wrapper:nth-child(2) .top {
transform: translate3d(200px, 0px, 0px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -45deg) translate3d(0, 50px, 50px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg) translate3d(0, -100px, 100px);
}
.wrapper:nth-child(2) .front {
transform: translate3d(200px, 0px, 0px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -45deg) translate3d(0, 50px, 50px);
}
.wrapper:nth-child(3) .top {
transform: translate3d(400px, 0px, 0px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -45deg) translate3d(0, 50px, 50px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg) translate3d(0, -100px, 100px);
}
.wrapper:nth-child(3) .front {
transform: translate3d(400px, 0px, 0px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -45deg) translate3d(0, 50px, 50px);
}
.wrapper:nth-child(4) .top {
transform: translate3d(600px, 0px, 0px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -45deg) translate3d(0, 50px, 50px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg) translate3d(0, -100px, 100px);
}
.wrapper:nth-child(4) .front {
transform: translate3d(600px, 0px, 0px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -45deg) translate3d(0, 50px, 50px);
}
```

The trick is not to use left properties, and do everything thru transforms.
Also, you need to set perspective-origin specifically, because it is working at the wrap level and not the base level.

**Editing**

I have spent some time trying to make this work in a more convenient way, bt I haven't succeeded. I leave what I have done here anyway, may be it can be in some way useful.

I wanted to leave the html and CSS working for webkit, setting transforms in the 3 levels.
Then , the idea was to set the **transform** property for IE calculated from the CSS.

The jQuery code is:

```
function set() {
    $(".top").each(function(index, value) { 
        var wrap = $(this).parent();
        var stage = $(wrap).parent();
        var tr = $(stage).css('WebkitTransform')
          + ' ' + $(wrap).css('WebkitTransform')
          + ' ' + $(this).css('WebkitTransform');
         $(this).css("transform", tr);
    });
}
```

I just can't figure out why this doesn't work.

Comment: Now I feel a little stupid, I never thought about using transform on the individual faces for positioning on stage, though it totally makes sense. So applying perspective to the direct parent seems to work (ie it doesn't breack backface visibility in IE) in case the direct children are the actual faces, instead of a transformed wrapper... it looks like this is the key, I'll go and test it.

Comment: Looks like I got my hopes up too soon, the perspective is correct, but backface visibility is broken with this solution too. Here's an example with a back side, the cuboid is rotated by 180°: http://jsfiddle.net/7GhPy/ Applying perspective to a parent simply doesn't seem to work in IE.

Comment: However you got me on the right track, I've tried it with my working cuboid where perspective is applied to the individual faces transforms. The trick is then to position the wrapper in the center of the stage, offset by `-wrapper width / 2`, and translate the faces on the x-axis (negative=left, positive=right) after perspective is applied. I need to do some further testing, but it looks like it's working.

Comment: Yes, it is a more elegant layout to have the wrapper in the center; I hope it works. I have added a failed attempt to set all this easier to the answer, hopefully it can be a way to make this easier

Comment: I think I got it, though it's flickering in Firefox, but that looks like an Fx bug, and at least on Safari for Windows (which isn't relevant anymore, I know, but I can't test it on OSX or iOS right now) it looks like everything's being rendered as a single layer, ie the faces of the different cubes drift into each other, however it's totally fine in Chrome and IE, and since it's easy to apply this solution to IE only it's not a problem right now, even though it would be nice if it were cross-browser compatible.

Comment: So, while I can't mark your answer as correct, since the code isn't working correctly as is, I can happily upvote it and award you with the bounty since your hint using transform for positioning on stage is what finally led me to a working solution. I'll post a working example later on.

Comment: OK, thanks and happy that it helped you. By the way, I have finally understood what is wrong with my jQuery. The webkitTransform aren't loaded in I.E., so the idea is wrong from the beginning. What I think that can work is to set the transforms via CSS (equals to -webkit-transform) and then group them via jQuery in the last child. (Resetting also the father and grand-father transforms)