# Does IE11 support css 3d transforms fully (preserve-3d)

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, internet-explorer-11

I am making a css 3d transforms web app, and I would like IE11 to be supported if possible. I know IE10 does not support the `preserve-3d` value for the `transform-style` css attribute, but I'm not sure about IE11. I have read some stuff that says that IE11 should support it, but the examples I tried didn't work properly (IE11 on Windows 8.1 here). So, does IE11 fully support css 3d transforms and `preserve-3d`?

Comment: [It apparently doesn’t.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) Sorry :(

Comment: This is sad when a Blackberry Browser has better support the IE....

Comment: @JoshPowell it wouldn't be the first time :)

Comment: The worst of all is that they are going without prefixes, (transform instead of -ms-transform), when IE transform support is the worst of all.

Comment: @vals good point there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft are adding support for `transform-style: preserve-3d`. It is supported in IE for Windows 10 tech preview.

Source: http://status.modern.ie

Blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/11/11/living-on-the-edge-our-next-step-in-interoperability.aspx

Comment: Support was added in the Windows 10 Edge browser, but not to IE11.

Answer (score 9):

According to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d), `transform-style: preserve-3d` is not supported by Internet Explorer as of version 11.

In the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#the_ms_transform_style_property), you can apparently manually apply the transformations to child elements to emulate the effect.

Comment: Thanks! Also good that you included a workaround, but don't expect anyone to go to that much trouble...especially to support IE

Comment: Ah well, [**I did**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203550/how-to-recreate-perspective-origin-effect-by-transforming-child-elements) (just in case someone is interested in an example), but I'm probably never going to do that again unless I'm getting paid in islands, it's just not worth the trouble :) @Markasoftware

Comment: @ndm agreed on the islands thing. This is one of those cases where IE costs waaaaaay too much to support.