# Cube not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

How to make this cube work on IE? I've been stuck here a week and still no success. Here is the `\JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Lg87gzu/4/

Here is the css code

I don't know what to do here, I've been working for a week right now. Any help must be appreciated.

```
.cube > div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 320px;
    width: 320px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.85);
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #202020;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.cube > div:first-child  {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(160px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(160px);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(160px);
    -ms-transform:rotateX(90deg) translateZ(160px);
}

.cube > div:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(160px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(160px);
    transform: translateZ(160px);
}

.cube > div:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(160px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(160px);
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(160px);
    text-align: center;
}

.cube > div:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(160px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(160px);
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(160px);
}

.cube > div:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(160px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(160px);
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(160px);
}

.cube > div:nth-child(5) p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.77em;
    margin: 40px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.cube > div:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotate(180deg) translateZ(160px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotate(180deg) translateZ(160px);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotate(180deg) translateZ(160px);
}

.cube {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 50ms linear;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-24deg) rotateY(20deg);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 50ms linear;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-24deg) rotateY(20deg);
    transition: transform 50ms linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateX(-24deg) rotateY(30deg);




}
```

Comment: As far as I know, IE doesn't support `transform-style: preserve-3d;`. Also you should include the code in your question, not just give a JSFiddle link. This will allow people in the future to find your post with all the information still intact (no broken links).

Comment: [MSDN: Transforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ie/hh673529(v=vs.85).aspx)  `[...]At this time, Internet Explorer 10 does not support the preserve-3d keyword. You can work around this by manually applying the parent element's transform to each of the child elements in addition to the child element's normal transform.[...]`  [SO: Does IE11 support css 3d transforms fully (preserve-3d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483742/does-ie11-support-css-3d-transforms-fully-preserve-3d)

Comment: can you put it out hold? zzzz