# Css Transition flip not working in IE/Firefox

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a div that is suppose to make a CSS flip transition when the user clicks go. It works perfectly in Google Chrome but Firefox & IE is a mess. The text just flips. Does anybody know whats causing this issue and if there is a way to resolve it.

Here is a jsfiddle of the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/kq45xhyv/

Please feel free to ask me any questions or let me know if you need any more information to help resolve this issue.

```
.flip-container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000; 
    padding:30px;
}


.flip-container.flip .flipper {
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%; 
}

.flipper {
   -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
   -o-transition: 0.6s;
   transition: 0.6s;
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
   position: relative; 
}

.front, .back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; }


  .front {
    z-index: 2; }

    .back {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
      transform: rotateY(180deg); }

      .backdrop{
        background-color: #edeff1;
        padding: 24px 23px 20px;
        border-radius: 6px;
      }
```

and here's the html

```
<div class='flip-container' id='myCard'>
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
                <div class="backdrop">      
                    <p>To start enter a URL below </p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='url'/>
                    </div>
                    <button class='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block'>GO</button>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="backdrop">  
                <div class="extra">
                    <p class='cent' id='finalURL'></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the other vendor prefixes (-moz- and -ms-) not just the -webkit- prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fierefox

In Firefox this looks like a possible bug to me, as it starts working when for example applying a zero degree rotation on the `.front` element.

```
.front {
    transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

Also you can see that the background disappears as expected when applying the background color to the `.front` element (ie the direct descendant of the transformed element) instead of the `.backdrop` element.

I have a feeling that `preserve-3d` is not being respected properly, but I'm just guessing here, all this 3D Rendering Context Hocus Pocus is like a closed book to me.

### Internet Explorer

And Internet Explorer, well IE doesn't support `preserve-3d`, if you want it to work there, then you'll have to transform the single `.front` and `.back` elements, I already had lots of fun with that:

- **[Why is backface-visibility hidden not working in IE10 when perspective is applied to parent elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622441/why-is-backface-visibility-hidden-not-working-in-ie10-when-perspective-is-applie)**
- **[How to recreate perspective-origin effect by transforming child elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203550/how-to-recreate-perspective-origin-effect-by-transforming-child-elements)**

### Note

Besides all that, your `perspective` value should have a unit, ie `px`!

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this was on the side burner. I submitted as the answer. Thank you!